# Python regex algorithm to find tags in text

Tags: python, regex

**My solution is already working, no problem with regex usage, but I wonder if there is a better approach to solve this, with or without regex.....**

I need to find `foo`,  `baa`, `bee`... and 100 more tags, including `foo baa`, `foo bee`.... on a given text like:

```
something foo something \n something else baa
```

And I need to do it over and over again, with many texts.

Some tags are grouped: maybe `foo` is the tag for `foo` and `foos` and `gaa`

So far my solution is to use a big regex like:

```
regex = r'(?P<foo>foos?|gaa)|(?P<baa>baa)....'
```

After compiling the regex:

```
match = re.finditer(compiled_re, text)
```

And finally

```
for m in match:
    print(m.lastgroup)

foo
baa
...
```

Some tags match for some words:

```
 tag  ---> words
'boo' ---> 'boo'
'foo' ---> 'foos' 'foo' 'gaa' 'foo-a' 'be ba' ...
```

Building the regex and adding new tags is not a problem

```
tags = {
    "foo": ['foos', 'foo', 'gaa', 'foo-a', 'be ba'],
    "boo": ['boo'],
    ...
}

def tag_regex(tags):
    boring computation
    return regex

> tag_regex(tags)
> r'(?P<foo>foos?|gaa|foo[-|\s]*a|be[-|\s]*ba)|(?P<boo>boo)....'
```

Comment: Yeah, be careful how you group things. Regex is a left to right proposition starting with the target position to the regex position. Be sure you are clear on what you want to match, then have at least a mid-level understanding of regex.

Comment: thanks @sln, but the regex is not a problem... the thing is, I guess it could be solved on a better way

Comment: If you have a large amount of permutations, let a super tool create a full blown regex trie, the fastest known regex possible. http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg. For instance a [175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) where it takes less than 5 steps to match any word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `ngrams` from `nltk`:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import ngrams

sentence = """something foo something \n
              something else baa and else foo bar"""

tags = ['foo', 'foo bar']

for tag in tags:
    print("Find tag: " + tag)

    n = len(word_tokenize(tag))
    nGrams = ngrams(word_tokenize(sentence), n)

    for gram in nGrams:
        gram =  ' '.join(gram)
        if gram == tag:
            print(gram)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Find tag: foo
foo
foo

Find tag: foo bar
foo bar
```

> I wonder if there is a better approach to solve this, with or without regex...

Strengths of the `ngrams` approach:

- Readability
- Maintainability (easier to debug/add new tags)

Furthermore, you can convert your regex approach to this ngram approach, for example for `r'foos?'` you can add `foo` and `foos` to the `tags`-list.

Comment: But when the tag is used for multiple words like tag foo is valid for word foo and gaa and foos... I guess wouldent work....

Comment: Thanks for effort, maybe i didnt make my point clear, I will edit it later, but the thing is, sometimes a tag can be valid for n multiple words, so with ngrams I would need to keep iterating over and over many combinations.... I sticky with the regex solution over the nltk for now

Comment: I edited, now a tag of size `n` can be found in tags of size `>n` as well. Hope it helps

Comment: Again, thanks, but I go for the regex solution because the tags are unknown word sizes, say it is 6,7,8 words len, there would be a much more computation over 100-200 tags for each text peace than a big regex with the words I need to find